# Как реализовать фильтр товаров с EAV?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, golang

Есть таблицы categories, products, props, props_value, приведу простой пример:
таблица categories - id, name .
таблица products - id, name, price . 
таблица props - id, name .
таблица props_value - prop_id, product_id, value

У каждой категории будет свой набор товаров соответственно разные значения фильтров. Хочу что бы в фильтре в категории выводились только те свойства и значения которые есть у товаров этой категории.
Для этого думаю сделать следующую таблицу categories_meta - id, category_id, prop_name, variants(json), 
эту табличку будет генерировать воркер допустим 1 раз в день, таким образом я получил все варианты свойст и значений для категории 1 дополнительным запросом в эту таблицу.
Но в текущей реализации мне не понятно как делать диф когда фильтром воспользовались, мне ведь нужно сделать варианты значений которые не подходят уже в выбранные свойства неактивными. 
Допустим пользователь выберет свойство "Цвет:красный:зеленый" и мне вернется 20 элементов из продуктов тут мне понятно как сделать, а если результатов будет не 20 а 20000 или больше, это же не разумно делать выборку 20к продуктов делать диф а потом делать еще 1 запрос в базу только уже с пагинацией.
Скажите как эту проблему можно решить, и насколько адекватное такое решения?

Заранее прошу прощения за нечеткое изложения мыслей.

Comment: Сложновато разобраться в вашем исходном коде. Но, сходу, наверное, в таблице props(id, name) нужно еще одно поле props(id, name, category_id), потому что `у каждой категории будут разные значения фильтров`.

Comment: не вижу красивого решения. 20к товаров (вернее только записей свойств, сама таблица товаров не нужна) может быть слишком медленным. с другой стороны, если у нас есть 20к товаров с уже выбранным фильтром, то и список возможных других значений не сильно сократиться. Насколько страшно, что вы покажете пользователю небольшое количество недопустимых значений. Вот когда товаров остается мало, тогда и для пользователя дальнейший выбор начинает резко сокращаться...

Comment: Если мы готовы пойти на применение усечения фильтров только для небольшого кол-ва товаров, то при сборе возможных значений можно поcчитать заодно количества с каждым из значений и на основе них принимать решение, когда включать отбор вариантов. Эти же количества можно использовать при оптимизации поиска (начинать с самых мелких групп, правда объяснить это sql оптимизатору может оказаться не тривиальной задачей)

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Скорее напрашивается еще одна таблица для связи категории-возможные props. потому что в БД наверняка существует довольно много фильтров, которые применимы к более чем одной категории товаров. те же цвета, размеры

Comment: Вторым решением будет кеширование полученных результатов отбора фильтров, т.е. сохранение готовых наборов зависимостей одних значений фильтров от других. где то это возможно поможет, но надо помнить, что сохранение объемного списка значений так же будет не самой дешевой операцией, особенно если пытаться сохранить в обычной БД.

Comment: Возможно из 20к товаров я переборщил но и 200 товаров выводить на страницу без пагинации это не есть хорошо, есть вариант в таблицу props еще добавить поле category_id, тогда по этому полю я смогу выбирать только нужные свойства для выбранной категории, но тогда есть другая проблема, если у меня свойство цвет имеет 30 вариантов значений а в категории "шапки" есть только 3 цвета, то мне желательно вывести только значения этих 3-х цветов.

Comment: Может кто-то может подсказать литературу или хорошею статью откуда можно почерпнуть знаний?

Comment: @Mike, да с динамическими полями куча вариантов. У товаров в категории "двояковыпуклые кастрюли" может быть две глубины, например.

Comment: вас никто не просит выводить все. а 200 товаров это уже приемлемые объемы что бы рассчитать на лету. тем более, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев пагинация делается с помощью limit, и если мы не на первой странице, то все предыдущие записи все равно будут прочитаны, перед тем как выведены нужные. А вообще я сильно сомневаюсь, что список допустимых фильтров надо получать в том же запросе что и товары. ведь при выборке товаров фильтры будут сгруппированы и отдельные значения не доступны. Скорее нам понадобится отдельный запрос только по таблице свойств

Comment: И при пагинации очень часто любят и кол-во товаров посчитать, что бы знать сколько страниц заранее, а это уже подъем с диска всех записей, которые нам нужны для составления списка фильтров ...